# google sheet what happen when submission reach 102

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found that if using a1notation, the A:A returns 102 cells array. Thus I just scroll down to the bottom and found a option to adding more rows.

The question is, what if the submission from a form just make the quantity of rows exceed the number of 102?

Thanks in advance~

Comment: Welcome. The system will add a new row, and insert the new form submission details. There will be 103 rows; and the same will happen as each form submissions is received.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thanks a lot dude~